# Search result doesn't retrieve list items in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Search result doesn't retrieve list items in SharePoint 2016 I have a site collection created in SharePoint 2016 on premis. I created serarch service application and it seems to work correctly except it doesn't retrieve any list items in the search result. Any idea will be appreciated

Regards
Ashraf

Answer (score 0):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7819a3cc-2b07-4656-aa75-872e400e2629/sharepoint-search-need-to-search-only-list-items?forum=sharepointsearch

1. In search center in results page, click Edit page.
2. In search results web part, click dropdown in the upper right corner -> click Edit Web Part.
3. Click Change query -> in Property filter field -> choose contentclass, Contains, Manual value, type STS_ListItem_Announcements  -> click Add property filter.
4. Repeat Step 3, type contentclass of list items you want to search excluding document, such as STS_ListItem_Comments, STS_ListItem_GenericList,   -> ok

For generic list add

```
"STS_List_GenericList": // Custom List
```

If it's a custom list template you can specify the type in a similar manner.  For example, for template type 10001 you could do STS_ListItem_1001.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a check list for you:

1. Go to Top-level Site -> Site Settings -> Result Types under Search section -> Check whether “SharePoint List Item” exist:
   [image]
2. Check whether Search is enable in your list:
   List Settings -> Advanced Settigns -> Search -> Select “Yes”:

[image]

3. Check whether you set filter to change query:

1)Navigate to your search center;
2)Go to Search Results page by entering some search query and clicking on search;
3)Once You are in Search results page, Click on Settings gear -> choose "Edit Page";
4)Locate "Search Results" web part, and choose "Edit this web part" from its context menu.
5)In the Web part properties panel, Click on "Change Query" button. Check whether you set filter to it.
[image]

if the error still exists, you can try to reset index and then start full crawl in Search Administration.

Comment: Everything seems to be correct configured as you explain above and I did index reset but it doesn't work.